# Automate DXA HTML design upload and publishing

Tags: dxa, sdl-tridion, dxa-1.7

We are using .NET DXA application, and for binary update, we manually upload the zip file and then publish the HTML design. It's a manual process and do the same every time the front end team updates anything in CSS. Can we setup an automated upload and publishing once we drop the zip file to particular folder location? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Certainly. High level steps how to do this:

1. Create a folder watcher which would detect the zip file when copied. Once the zip is detected it would be processed and moved out of the folder (success/failed folders). Processing takes place in steps 2 and 3 below
2. Upload the zip using the Stream Core Service
3. Publish the HTML design using (regular) Core Service

Steps 1. and 3. are pretty straightforward, for 2. take a look [here](https://yatb.mitza.net/2013/05/create-multimedia-component-using-core.html) how to use the stream client. Note that the blog is somewhat old, but the principle is the same. You can make use of the new stream endpoints as well.

Comment: Indeed, we’re doing something similar in-house for the DXA development. We have integrated this in the CI build for the HTML Design (which triggers on code changes).